# counting rows if any one of the field is empty in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have several columns in my table if any of the column is empty it should be count as 1...at the same time if 2 or more columns empty in same row...it should not count as 2...
help me the mysql query.....

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$unit=$_GET['unit'];
$chapter=$_GET['chapter'];
//$dept=$_GET['dept'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from `$unit` where stopic='$chapter'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $a=$row['ch1'];
        $b=$row['ch2'];
        $c=$row['ch3'];
        $d=$row['ch4'];
        $e=$row['ans'];
        $f=$row['ques'];
    }
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
?>
```

if $a or $b or $c or $d or $e or $f is empty...it should count as 1...per row only once..not to count as 2 for the same row

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem.
Maybe this will help - you can use the `isempty()` function, which will return true if your variable is empty.

Make a variable named empty and give it value 0. Then on your for loop add this:

```
if(isempty($a)||isempty($b)||isempty($c)||isempty($d)||isempty($e)||isempty($f))
   $empty++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$unit=$_GET['unit'];
$chapter=$_GET['chapter'];
//$dept=$_GET['dept'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from `$unit` where stopic='$chapter'");
$empty_record = 0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $a=$row['ch1'];
        $b=$row['ch2'];
        $c=$row['ch3'];
        $d=$row['ch4'];
        $e=$row['ans'];
        $f=$row['ques'];

        if($a=='' || $b=='' || $c=='' || $d=='' || $e=='' || $f=='')
        {
            $empty_record++;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
echo $empty_record;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$unit=$_GET['unit'];
$chapter=$_GET['chapter'];
//$dept=$_GET['dept'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from `$unit` where stopic='$chapter'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $numOfEmpty = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        for($i = 0;$i<count($result);$i++) {
             if ($result[$i] == "") { 
                $numOfEmpty++;
                break;
             }
        }
    }
    echo $numOfEmpty;
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Please let me know however, if the code works. :)